# Program exits before running logic

Tags: f#

I'm playing around with some charting examples on this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297119(v=vs.100).aspx) page but it seems that the application pops up a charting window and then exits immediately before rendering the actual chart. Here is the example that I'm trying to run titled 'Retrieving Data in the Background'.

```
open System
open System.Threading
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms
open FSharp.Charting
open System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

/// Add data series of the specified chart type to a chart
let addSeries typ (chart : Chart) = 
    let series = new Series(ChartType = typ)
    chart.Series.Add(series)
    series

/// Create form with chart and add the first chart series
let createChart typ = 
    let chart = new Chart(Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Palette = ChartColorPalette.Pastel)
    let mainForm = new Form(Visible = true, Width = 700, Height = 500)
    let area = new ChartArea()
    area.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor <- Color.LightGray
    area.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor <- Color.LightGray
    mainForm.Controls.Add(chart)
    chart.ChartAreas.Add(area)
    chart, addSeries typ chart

let chart, series = createChart SeriesChartType.FastLine
let axisX = chart.ChartAreas.[0].AxisX
let axisY = chart.ChartAreas.[0].AxisY

chart.ChartAreas.[0].InnerPlotPosition <- new ElementPosition(10.0f, 2.0f, 85.0f, 90.0f)

let updateRanges (n) = 
    let values = 
        seq { 
            for p in series.Points -> p.YValues.[0]
        }
    axisX.Minimum <- float n - 500.0
    axisX.Maximum <- float n
    axisY.Minimum <- values |> Seq.min |> Math.Floor
    axisY.Maximum <- values |> Seq.max |> Math.Ceiling

let ctx = SynchronizationContext.Current

let updateChart (valueX, valueY) = 
    async { 
        do! Async.SwitchToContext(ctx)
        if chart.IsDisposed then 
            do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()
            return false
        else 
            series.Points.AddXY(valueX, valueY) |> ignore
            while series.Points.Count > 500 do
                series.Points.RemoveAt(0)
            updateRanges (valueX)
            do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()
            return true
    }

let randomWalk = 
    let rnd = new Random()

    let rec loop (count, value) = 
        async { 
            let count, value = count + 1, value + (rnd.NextDouble() - 0.5)
            Thread.Sleep(20)
            let! running = updateChart (float count, value)
            if running then return! loop (count, value)
        }
    loop (0, 0.0)

Async.Start(randomWalk)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Async.Start` operation starts the asynchronous workflow in the background and then finishes as soon as the background work is added to a queue. If your program finishes right after that, then the background work never gets to run.

If you are writing application using Windows Forms, then you probably need something like:

```
Async.Start(randomWalk)
Application.Run(mainForm)
```

The `Start` call will schedule the work and the `Run` call will pass control to Windows Forms to run the application until `mainForm` is closed.

In other contexts, you could handle this differently - in script, your code would work, because F# Interactive keeps running the background work after a command is executed. In a console application, you could run `Console.ReadLine` and let the user terminate the application by hitting enter at any point.